# I need to display the contents of a method that is in another method in java

Tags: java

I need to display the numbers that are generated in another method that is in another class, I called the method and it works however it is displaying the name of both classes and the name of the method instead of the contents of the variables.

This is the main class where I call the method:

```
National i = new National();                       
i.natDraw();
System.out.println(i);
```

this is the method I need to get the variables from:

```
public class National {
    public static void natDraw() {
        //generate 10 random numbers for the draw
        Random r = new Random();
        int n1 = r.nextInt(99);
        int n2 = r.nextInt(99);
        int n3 = r.nextInt(99);
        int n4 = r.nextInt(99);
        int n5 = r.nextInt(99);
        int n6 = r.nextInt(99);
        int n7 = r.nextInt(99);
        int n8 = r.nextInt(99);
        int n9 = r.nextInt(99);
        int n10 = r.nextInt(99);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have 2 options, you can override `toString()` in the `National` class and have it print out the numbers.  Or you can just call the printouts within the `natDraw()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The variables in natDraw are local in scope, additionally you are trying to print out the instance of the class itself not the variables you want to print.

Change your natDraw() method to return a Collection of the random variables if you want to get those values in another class. Then you can iterate through you collection and print out those values in your main class.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to implement National like this:

```
class National
{
    public static List<Integer> getNatDraw()
    {
        final int drawAmount = 10;
        final Random rand = new Random();

        final List<Integer> natDraw = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < drawAmount; ++i)
        {
            natDraw.add(rand.nextInt(99));
        }

        return natDraw;
    }
}
```

That way it returns them from the getNatDraw() method.
You can do the following in another class with access to the method:

```
System.out.println(National.getNatDraw());
```

This is an example of output for that call:

```
[84, 63, 52, 18, 3, 57, 0, 74, 37, 70]
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the variables that you have just created in a separate method, I would store your variables in an array, and loop through the array of a set size in order to store the variables without having to rewrite code.  I would also make this array publicly accessible from this separate class.

```
public class National{
    public static  int[] rndInts = new int[10]; //your array
    public static void natDraw() {//your method to create the random variables
       for(int i: rndInts){//loop through using a for each loop
           i = r.nextInt(99);//store each value in the array
       }
    }
}
```

This array can be accessed using National.rndInts to return the array.
When you call  `System.out.println(i);`it calls the .toString() method of the object `i`